# Getting values from an iterable object without using a loop

Tags: java, loops, iterable

In Java, how do I retrieve elements from an iterable object without looping?

Comment: It depends on type of dataset.

Comment: Have you checked the API for your DataSet?

Comment: Please post real code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you can write for-each loop, your `dataset` is `Iterable<T>`.

```
Vartype var = dataset.iterator().next();
```

It will throw an exception if `dataset` is empty.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(dataset.size() == 1)
   number = dataset.get(0); //if collections

if(dataset.length == 1)
number = dataset[0];    //if array
```

Comment: @hexacyanide u r using it and u dont know ? see anything similar values or you can calculate it's size by taking one for-each loop.

Comment: I've seen infinite implementations of `Iterable<T>` — `hasNext()` of their iterators always returned `true`, and naturally, they didn't have any `size` or `length` or `count` or whatever fields/methods. Probably the author was in love with Scheme's infinite lists, or whatever, but the fact is that you sometimes run into such things.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of double-edged.  Since we don't know what `Vartype` is, we can't tell you implicitly if it's immutable or not.

If it doesn't change, you can treat it like a singleton and access its first element.

```
var.get(0);
```

If the size *can* change, then you would want to continue using the enhanced-for.